# Prove that L = {$w∈${a,b,c}$^*$|w contains "abc"} is regular with Nerode theorem?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

How to prove that  $L = \{w \in \{a,b,c\}^* \mid w \text{ contains } abc \}$ is regular using the Nerode theorem?

**Attempt** 
If I show that there are a finite number of equivalence classes for this language then by Nerode theorem it's regular. 
I found two equivalence classes: $S_0 = L[(b+ac+abb)^*]$, $S_1 = L[((b+ac+abb)^*a(a+ab+abb)^*)^*]$ but got stuck on $S_2, S_3$. 
Also, here is an image of the language automata: 
[image]

Comment: Looks like $S_3$ should be the entire $L$, then $S_1$ should be all words not in $L$ that end with $a$, $S_2$ should be all words not in $L$ which end with $ab$, and $S_0$ should be all the remaining words not in $L$. I guess it is a bit of work to prove that elements in each of those classes are equivalent to each other.

Comment: There should be another loop labelled by $c$ around $q_0$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to use Nerode's theorem to prove that $L$ is regular? Setting $A = \{a,b,c\}$, one has $L = A^*abcA^*$ and thus $L$ is clearly regular.

Comment: That's the task I was given, and I need to practice proving regularity with Nerode theorem.